# How to build an Advanced filter panel for a Grid component in ExtJS 5

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs-grid

I am required to build an advanced search / filter panel for a given grid component(on ExtJS 5).

============================================

Search fields:

field1: textfield    field2: numberfield    field3: date   field4: lov

---

Table Grid:

name    |    age    |    date    |   status

---

So the filter fields would actually be built on top of the fields that grid is referring to(basically mirror the fields).

On entering any criteria and hitting search in search fields panel, the grid's store has to be reloaded with new criteria.
This is what i want to do. But, I could not find anything regarding this in extjs docs or any guides/tutorials on any forums.

Is there anything that Extjs gives that app developer can consume(like a plug and play, with min config to specify fields etc.)
If not, there any guides / tutorials out there which i can use to build this.

Appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Filtering done this way is not a trivial to implement so it cannot be explained in one sentence or article. Anyway, see this commercial plugin, it probably does what you want: http://extjs.eu/software/ext-grid-multisearch-plugin

Comment: Thanks Saki. I did checkout this plugin. Though the functionality matches (almost) my requirement, The UI is little different(eg: specifying the criteria operand like 'contains', 'equals', 'starts with' as an explicit field) and also would need to make it configurable runtime(though this could already be possible with the plugin you have mentioned).
I atleast want to try and build this component(though it could be a struggle initially), before i try using commercial plugin.